# Function and difference in make between $ and $$

Tags: makefile

In the Makefile, there is sometimes the notation `$` and sometimes it is `$$`. When should those be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ is used in Makefiles to escape the $ e.g. you have a variable in the environment of the shell you want to use

```
@echo "Building in $$PWD"
```